# Nested select in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a bit(10) string, I want to perform AND operation, then get number of 1s and divide it by the length of the bit string (by 10 in this case). This is the query:

```
select  a.doc
       , a.sentenceid
       , b.doc
       , b.sentenceid
       , LENGTH( REPLACE( CAST( select a.tokenizedsentence & b.tokenizedsentence AS TEXT ), '0', '')) / LENGTH(a.tokenizedsentence)
from 
  nlpdata a, nlpdata b
where 
  a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid;
```

When using alone, both of the queries work, but how to combine them?

```
select a.sentenceid
      , b.sentenceid
      , a.tokenizedsentence & b.tokenizedsentence 
from nlpdata a, nlpdata b;
```

and

```
select length( replace( cast( tokenizedsentence AS TEXT ), '0', ''))
from nlpdata;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `Select` inside the `CAST`. Remove the `Select` to fix the error

```
SELECT a.doc,
       a.sentenceid,
       b.doc,
       b.sentenceid,
       Length(Replace(Cast(a.tokenizedsentence & b.tokenizedsentence AS TEXT), '0', '')) / Length(a.tokenizedsentence)
FROM   nlpdata a 
INNER JOIN nlpdata b
        ON a.sentenceid < b.sentenceid;
```

As a side note always use `INNER JOIN` to Join two tables instead of old style comma separated join.

performance wise there won't be any difference. `INNER JOIN` is more readable then `comma separated join` where both **filters** and **join** condition will be present in `Where` clause. In `Inner Join` you can keep the join condition `ON` clause and move the filters to `Where` clause

Comment: Thanks a lot. And why is `INNER JOIN` better than `nlpdata a, nlpdata b` ?